# How to execute ActionView, ERB::Util from ./script/console in Rails 2.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I develop it in Ruby on Rails 2.0.5 now.

Can I execute link_to method and the url_escape method use in /script/console?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy to use `url_encode` (I assume that's what you mean):

```
>> ERB::Util.erb_encode("hello world")
=> "hello%20world"
```

For helpers in ActionView, you can do:

```
>> helper.link_to "you", "some_url"
=> "<a href=\"some_url\">you</a>"
```